# iPhone Memory Error - when using Build & Debug, How to debug?

Tags: iphone, debugging, memory, simulator

I'm a newbie and need some help with an iPhone App running on the Simulator. The app works fine running with Build & Run or Build & Run - breakpoints off, but blows when running with Build & Debug - Breakpoints on. Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Lon

Specifics: No breakpoints set, never gets to any visible simulator results, seems to blow during initialization phase before it can generate any output. Source of app is the DrinkMixer example, in the "Head First iPhone development" book (example built up to page 280) by Dan & Tracey Pilone.

Blows With this Error Message:

```
Attaching to process 970.
Pending breakpoint 1 - "*0x01c1b001" resolved
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc
---
Leaks:
The only object noted as "leaked Object" is:
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 128 Bytes <blank> 0x3c11950   128Bytes   CoreGraphics    open_handle_to_dylib_path
___

Object Allocations shows (Highest at top = CFString):

Category   --- Overall Bytes  --  #Overall    -- Live Bytes --  #Living
* All Allocations * 497kb      #5888    496kb   #5878   10
CFString                42kb     #1126   42kb       
Malloc  32.00 KB    32kb     #1     32kb
Malloc 1.00 KB  29kb     #29        29kb
Malloc 8.00 KB  24kb     #3     24kb    
Malloc 32 Bytes 20.81kb  #666   20.75kb
Malloc 1.50 KB  19.5kb    #13       19.5kb 
CFDictionary (key-store)    17.64kb  #159  17.64kb 

(note:  Except for "All Allocations, the  #Living is the same as #Overall)
---

List of Calls from Debugger:

#0  0x01c1b010 in CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings
#1  0x023a0779 in LoadFontPathCache
#2  0x023a096b in Initialize
#3  0x023a0f3e in GSFontCreateWithName
#4  0x003d4575 in +[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:]
#5  0x002cddaa in +[UINavigationButton defaultFont]
#6  0x002d9e37 in -[UINavigationButton initWithValue:width:style:barStyle:possibleTitles:tintColor:]
#7  0x002cdc75 in -[UINavigationButton initWithImage:width:style:]
#8  0x00468eeb in -[UIBarButtonItem(Static) createViewForNavigationItem:]
#9  0x002d1b56 in -[UINavigationItem customRightView]
#10 0x002d20e3 in -[UINavigationItem updateNavigationBarButtonsAnimated:]
#11 0x002d1e1a in -[UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:]
#12 0x00002e7b in -[RootViewController viewDidLoad] at RootViewController.m:41
#13 0x00313796 in -[UIViewController view]
#14 0x00311d92 in -[UIViewController contentScrollView]
#15 0x0031c2b4 in -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:]
#16 0x0031b32e in -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:]
#17 0x0031cd1a in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
#18 0x0031831a in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded]
#19 0x004362e4 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
#20 0x035342b0 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
#21 0x0353406f in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
#22 0x035338c6 in CA::Context::commit_transaction
#23 0x0353353a in CA::Transaction::commit
#24 0x00295ef9 in -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished]
#25 0x0029bb88 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
#26 0x002976d3 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
#27 0x0029e0b5 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#28 0x023a3ed1 in PurpleEventCallback
#29 0x01bb6b80 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#30 0x01bb5c48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#31 0x00295e69 in -[UIApplication _run]
#32 0x0029f003 in UIApplicationMain
#33 0x00002ba0 in main at main.m:14
```

---

The code, including line #41 (noted below) is as follows. And thanks for the formatting help and comment:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"  
#import "DrinkDetailViewController.h";
#import "DrinkConstants.h"
#import "AddDrinkViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize drinks, addButtonItem;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    //  add PATH for PLIST  
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"DrinkDirections"  ofType:@"plist"]; 
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]                              initWithContentsOfFile:path];   
    self.drinks = tmpArray; 
    [tmpArray release];

// Next is Line #41 - I removed earlier empty lines & Comments

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButtonItem;

}
- (IBAction) addButtonPressed: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Add button pressed!");
```

---

Comment: So what do you do around line 41 of RootViewController.m ? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Instruments and NSZombie detection:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/